# Why can I push to a private git repository even it's private

Tags: git, github, ssh

I create a private repository on Github, when I try to clone it I can't (and that's what I was waiting for), but if I init a new git project on my local machine and set a remote origin url I can push my commits on this repo without any problem...

Is that normal ?

I was waiting that I have a forbidden error because I didn't give any access to the user I have on my local machine.

Comment: Do you use the same url in both cases ?

Comment: You'll have to provide a reproducer ([mre] preferable), otherwise we'll just be guessing. Note, though, that we *can* say that GitHub have two ways to decide who you are: ssh, and https. These two ways produce different results, so you'll have to say which of these you're using.

Comment: @LeGEC yes, and when I verified on github I found my commits

Comment: @torek I used ssh

Comment: OK - when using ssh, GItHub decides *who you are* by *which public key you send them* (specifically, the first one that you send that works; you can try a few "wrong" keys before they give up on you). So the next step is to determine which public key(s) you're sending from each machine, and why you're sending those keys. Use `ssh -Tv git@github.com` to observe the negotiations.

Comment: Once GitHub have decided that you are `user12345` or whatever mapping they have for that public key, you have full access to whatever `user12345` has on GItHub. So your issue is that you're authenticating yourself as a person who *does* have access to these repositories, when you think (and intend) that you are/should-be authenticating as a *different* person who *does not* have access.

Comment: The **only thing that matters to GitHub here** is the *public key* you send. The actual user name you're using on your computer, and the `user.name` stored in a Git configuration file, are entirely irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks @torek for your detailed reply.
Indeed, I have two github accounts (let say A and B) and I my problem is why can I push commits with user A on my repository B which is private and the settings do not contain any ssh key of user A.

Answer (score 1):

> Indeed, I have two github accounts (let say A and B) and I my problem is why can I push commits with user A on my repository B which is private and the settings do not contain any ssh key of user A.

Then it is best to differentiate those two accounts, using two different SSH keys, registered each to their respective accounts.

Do that with a `~/.ssh/config` file with:

```
Host githubA
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keyA

Host githubB
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keyB
```

Check that are working with:

```bash
ssh -Tv githubA
ssh -Tv githubB
```

And clone your repositorys with:

```bash
git clone githubA:A/repoFromA
git clone githubB:B/repoFromB
```

From there, a push from each local repository will use the right SSH key and will authenticate to GitHub with the right account.